# Invalid iMessage App from App Store

Tags: ios, imessage

We submitted an app with an iMessage sticker extension to App Store under Xcode8.0. After we submitted the archive file we got an error mail:

> Invalid iMessage App - Your iMessage app contains an invalid sticker
>   pack.

The app may have been built or signed with a non-compliant or pre-release tools. For more information, go to developer.apple.com.

We updated the Xcode to the newest version. Anyone who knows how to fix it? Thx

Comment: is  xcode beta or stable ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error too and I was using Xcode 8 GM seed and valid provisioning profiles.
What fixed it for me was generating the iOS App Archive and exporting the build for distribution. 
To generate the iOS App Archive follow the steps from [Apple'
s Documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html)